# TensorFlow: Create a new tensor based on list of indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning tensorflow right now, and I have a question that I couldn't find via google. I find it easier to work on a problem and look up documentation as I stumble on issues, so if this is somewhere in the documentation and I haven't applied, I apologize.

I have a tensor. Let's say it's 100 x 1. Let's call it **t1**. I also have a list of integers, ranging in [0, 99], of size 5000, call it **l**. I want to transform **t1** into a 5000 x 1 tensor, call it **t2**.

The relationship is as follows: suppose the i^th entry of **l** is j. Then, I want the i^th entry of **t2** to be equal to the j^th entry of **t1**.

Now, if these were numpy arrays, I would simply do:

```
    t2 = t1[l]
```

But I don't think this is an efficient way of doing it in tensorflow, and it doesn't even seem to work anyways.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is tf.gather:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()
t1 = tf.random_normal((100, 1))
l = tf.random_uniform((5000, ), minval=0, maxval=99, dtype=tf.int32)
t2 = tf.gather(t1, l)
```

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much!